# Segmentation fault even though I can compile my code (CS50 week 2 substitution problem)

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, cs50

even though I can compile my code here, if I run this code, it says 'segmentation fault.'  I'm trying to encrypt the message. for more details: https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2021/psets/2/substitution/

Is something wrong with my code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if(argc == 2) 
    {
        if(isalpha(argv[1]))
        {
            if(strlen(argv[1]) == 26)
            {
                char lower[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
                char upper[] = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'};
        
                string plaintext = get_string("plaintext: ");
        
                for(int k = 0, n = strlen(plaintext); k < n; k++)
                {
                    for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
                    {   
                    
                        if(plaintext[k] == upper[i])
                        {
                            upper[i] = argv[1][i];
                            printf("%c", argv[1][i]);
                        }
                        else if(plaintext[k] == lower[i])
                        {
                            lower[i] = argv[1][i];
                            printf("%c", argv[1][i]);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            printf("%c", plaintext[k]);
                        }
                    }
                }
                printf("\n");
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Key must contain 26 characters.\n");
                return 1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Key must contain 26 characters.\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("Usage: ./substitution key\n");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: `isalpha(argv[1])` is wrong. The argument to `isalpha()` is a `char`, but `argv[1]` is `char*`.

Comment: Why are you modifying the `upper` and `lower` arrays in your loop?

Comment: If you want to check that `argv[1]` is all alphabetic, you have to loop through the entire string, calling `isalpha()` on each character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `isalpha(argv[1])` you pass a pointer (i.e. `argv[1]`) but `isalpha` expects a `char`.

Besides that your code is much more complicated than needed. A simpler approach is to calculate an index into the key from the plain text.

Examples:

If a plain text letter is a 'B', you want to get the second letter in the key. To do that simply do `index = 'B' - 'A'`, i.e. index will be 1. And the encoded letter will be `toupper(argv[1][1])`.

If a plain text letter is a 'C', you want to get the second letter in the key. To do that simply do `index = 'C' - 'A'`, i.e. index will be 2. And the encoded letter will be `toupper(argv[1][2])`.

So in code something like:

```
            if (isupper(plaintext[k]))
            {
                int index = plaintext[k] - 'A';
                result[k] = toupper(argv[1][index]);
            }
```

If a plain text letter is a 'b', you want to get the second letter in the key. To do that simply do `index = 'b' - 'a'`, i.e. index will be 1. And the encoded letter will be `tolower(argv[1][1])`.

If a plain text letter is a 'c', you want to get the second letter in the key. To do that simply do `index = 'c' - 'a'`, i.e. index will be 2. And the encoded letter will be `tolower(argv[1][2])`.

```
            if (islower(plaintext[k]))
            {
                int index = plaintext[k] - 'a';
                result[k] = tolower(argv[1][index]);
            }
```

Putting it together (with a fixed plain text):

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if(argc != 2) 
    {
        printf("Usage: ./substitution key\n");
        return 1;
    }
    
    if(strlen(argv[1]) != 26)
    {
        printf("Key must contain 26 characters.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    char plaintext[30] = "HeLlO woRLd";
    char result[30] = {0};
    for(int k = 0, n = strlen(plaintext); k < n; k++)
    {
        if (isupper(plaintext[k]))
        {
            result[k] = toupper(argv[1][plaintext[k] - 'A']);
        }
        else if (islower(plaintext[k]))
        {
            result[k] = tolower(argv[1][plaintext[k] - 'a']);
        }
        else
        {
            result[k] = plaintext[k];
        }
    }
    puts(result);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
EhBbQ pqLBs
```

Comment: I can't understand the lines here: 
char plaintext[30] = "HeLlO woRLd";
char result[30] = {0};
Why did you say these here?

Comment: opps! I think I know the reason why. Thank you for your help. really appreciated.